# how do I post to the API with the parameter "COUNTRY_ID" while there is no event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

this is my state

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      merchants:[],
    }
  }
```

and this is react lifecycle

```
componentWillMount() {
    return this.setState({
      COUNTRY_ID: this.props.resGet('country_id')
    })
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await Api.post('language/merchant', this.state)
    .then((response) => {
      let responseJson = response
      console.log(responseJson)
      if(responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
        this.setState({
          merchants:response.data.DATA
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

This is the initial state with the `"merchant []"`property, then `"merchant []"` will be filled with the results of the request that will be posted to the API with the parameter of `"COUNTRY_ID"`, how to enter `"COUNTRY_ID"` into the state then I post the parameter `" COUNTRY_ID "`to the API?

Comment: Use input text box for country_id if it is to be taken by user, or it is static just append in url. I think what you are doing in componentWillMount is wrong, you don't return `this.setState`. Are you getting country_id from props?

Answer (score 2):

[ComponentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) is

> considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code.

`componentDidMount` will execute right after `render` which will execute right after `componentWillMount`, so, if `componentWillMount` has async functions, you'll probably not find their results when `componentDidMount` is called,

You can pust what you have in `componentWillMount` inside `componentDidMount` like :

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const countryID = this.props.resGet('country_id');

  await Api.post('language/merchant', countryID)
  .then((response) => {
    let responseJson = response
    console.log(responseJson)
    if(responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
      this.setState({
        merchants:response.data.DATA,
        COUNTRY_ID: countryID
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This can't be done because I will post the parameters to the postman using the body, so it can't be saved in this url causing an error 500